# "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]" - MP3 & VC

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp3, typeerror, discord.js

I am encountering an error when my discord bot is trying to play an MP3 file in a Voice channel.

My code:

```
if(message.member.voiceChannel){

        const connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./resources/shamebell.mp3');

        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Finished playing!');
          });

          dispatcher.destroy(); // end the stream
}
```

The bot encounters an error when trying to play the MP3 file. It joins the Voice Channel that the user is in just fine. The bot should join the VC, play the MP3 file then leave afterwards.

Error in dispatcher:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string
```

I have tried using both the absolute path as well as the relative path to the MP3. FFMPEG is installed and windows PATH set as well as NPM installed "ffmpeg-binaries": "^3.2.2-3".

Swapping from `connection.playFile('./resources/shamebell.mp3');` to `connection.play('./resources/shamebell.mp3');` Gives the error `connection.play is not a function` at line 14:43

Any help on resolving this issue will be appreciated :)

New code with Discordv12 installed:

```
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
const dispatcher = connection.play('resources/shamebell.mp3');

dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Finished playing!');
  });
  dispatcher.destroy();
```

Same issue:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string
```

Path to MP3 file:
    C:\Users\Test\Desktop\bot\BotTest\resources\shamebell.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the debugger in VSC and it turns out ffmpeg-static was the issue. The error was being masked.

`Error: Cannot find module 'ffmpeg-static'`

Installing ffmpeg-static via npm solved the issue.

Can now play MP3s

Answer (score 1):

To use `.play()`  you need to install `discord.js v12` wich is recommended for Voice Stuff by doing `npm i discordjs/discord.js` this will get you the newest version.

> Warning `discord.js` master/v12 has breaking changes but a full voice rewrite and a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: installed npm i discordjs/discord.js & changed the playFile to ```connection.play('./resources/shamebell.mp3');``` but now nothing happens. The bot doesn't even join the VC

Comment: I removed everything from the if , it now joins the channel but says the same thing ```TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string```